# I'm using stored procedure in phpmyadmin to calculate fine for library management system

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, xampp

```
CASE 
WHEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE,books_transaction.date_out)>10 
    THEN UPDATE books_transaction SET books_transaction.fine = 50 
    ELSE UPDATE books_transaction SET books_transaction.fine = 100
END CASE;
END
```

> ERROR #1054 unknown column 'date_out' in 'field list'

Comment: Every statement needs a terminator. And there is no end case in sql just end will do

Comment: Please don't edit to make less legible and read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Error message is very clear - also please publish table definition.

Comment: `phpMyAdmin` is an application written in PHP to make life easier for people administrating a MYSQL DBMS. It does not have Stored Proceedures, MySQL however does. Terminology unfortunately does matter

Comment: Check your schema. Looks like the `books_transaction` table does not have a `date_out` column

Comment: table columns are only available when using a select,update or delete. You cannot invoke them in the way you are trying to. See @akina answer.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
UPDATE books_transaction 
SET fine = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE,date_out)>10 
                THEN 50
                ELSE 100 
                END;
```